# Есть ли лимит запросов в секунду/минуту?

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Использую yandex-geocoding-api, раньше работал с другим сервисом геокодинга и там был лимит на число запросов с одного ip в секунду. Есть ли подобное ограничение в данном сервисе?

Документацию само собой изучил, но нашёл упоминания только о суточном лимите.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничений на количество запросов в секунду/минуту нет. Как и заявлено в документации, на текущий момент ограничения есть для суточного количества запросов, например, в 25 000 в бесплатной версии.

Однако, использование API Яндекс.Карт для парсинга данных запрещено пользовательским соглашением. Такой сервис может быть заблокирован автоматически.

Убедитесь, что ваш проект не нарушает пункты соглашения и условий использования.

Comment: Да, количество запросов в секунду нигде в документации строго не фиксировано. Но не рекомендуется превышать лимит в 10-20 запросов в секунду для бесплатных тарифов. При превышении лимита не гарантирована скорость (и факт) ответа, и может быть включено принудительное ограничение RPS со стороны сервиса.